# Does chrome.identity get the id of the user's google account or of the individual browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Reading about how it works it sounds like `identity` is getting the browser's unique id, but the api keeps on referring to the account id. And if it is an account id how do you get the id if the user isn't signed in? And is there any alternative if the user doesn't have a google account?

Answer (score 0):

As this [document](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#type-AccountInfo) stated:

> **AccountInfo**
>
> -A unique identifier for the account. This ID will not change for the lifetime of the account.

This will now confirm that chrome.indentity gets the id of the account and not the browser's id.

---

If your user doesn't have any google account you may follow these [steps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#non):

> 1. Register with the provider.
> 2. Add permissions for provider resources
>      that your app will access.
> 3. Get the authentication token.

You need to register an OAuth2 client ID with the provider and configure the client ID as a website.

Hope this helps.